# How do I apply a mathematical mysql query to each row in a database?

Tags: php, mysql

I am designing a database for an MMORPG, and the administrator back end. I need a function that will allow me to add a specified amount of the game's primary currency: `Gold` to each account in the database.

**This is what I have:**

```
function massAddGold($gold_amount){
    dbconnect();
    $value=mysql_query("SELECT * from `mmo_db1`.`users`;");
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($value)){
        $currentgold=$row['gold'];
        $newgold=$currentgold+$gold_amount;
        mysql_query("UPDATE  `mmo_db1`.`users` SET  `gold` =  \"$newgold\";");
    }
    dbclose();
}
```

where `mmo_db1` is the name of the database.

When I execute the command, `massAddGold("50");` I then check the database. It takes the row with the highest value of `Gold`, adds the `50 gold` to that, then applies that value to all of the rows. I need it to execute on each row individually.

Comment: A few notes: 
Don't use the mysql_ functions in new applications; use mysqli or PDO.
You don't need to add semicolons to the end of queries (most of the time).
You can use single quotes for string data in queries so you don't have to escape double quotes.

Comment: Your code is HIGHLY racy. By the time you pull up a user's gold value, it could have been changed elsewhere, and you overwrite it with the old value. Good for people who just bought something expensive. bad for those who just got a lot of gold. Either way, you're going to make a LOT of people mad with this kind of bad code

Comment: G-NUGGET, I have never used either one, I was taught using MySQL. I am looking into PDO right now, and trying to figure everything out. Also, I tried using single quotes, and it simply passed a NULL value.

Marc B., I am open to suggestions on improving this code. I already implemented Adrian's solution below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do it in two queries what is wrong with one

```
UPDATE users SET  gold = gold + 50;
```

Answer (score 1):

mysql_query("UPDATE  `mmo_db1`.`users` SET  `gold` =  gold+50");

ps, mysql* =bad

Answer (score 1):

Why do a select first? If you want to give everyone an extra 50 gold, why not do something like:

```
UPDATE  `mmo_db1`.`users` SET  `gold` =  `gold`+ $newgold;
```

Comment: Are you sure - PHP substitutes variables in double quotes

Comment: @AdrianCornish The entire query is in double quotes, so the second escaped double quotes seem superflous. I guess it threw me seeing the output of `update ... set gold="$newgold"...` but yes, you are right, no need for concat operators.

Comment: Agree it is a bit weird to convert an int to string to pass back to the DB :-)